How to get and set the order of elements in a GridView with DelegateModel for drag and drop
I have made a grid with 3x3 button in Qt 5 qml. With drag and drop it is possible to change the order of the elements (permutation). The underlaying data is a C++ model. But on drop I do not want to change the C++ model data. Instead I want to have the order in a separated list of indices. On showing the grid I want to set the button order according to a list (readList) and on leaving I want to get the new list from the button order (writeList).
Item {
    id: root
    anchors.fill: parent

    onVisibleChanged: {
        if (visible) { readOrder() } else { writeOrder() }
    }
    function readOrder() {
        // TODO set visual indices           
    }
    function writeOrder() {
        // TODO get visual indieces
        for(var i = 0; i < id_delegateModel.items.count; ++i) {
            let item1 = id_delegateModel.items.get(i)       // -> always undefined
            let item2 = id_gridView.model.items.get(i)      // -> always undefined
            let item3 = id_gridView.itemAtIndex(i)
            let visualIndex = item3.data[1].visualIndex     // -> prints Critical 
        }
    }

    Flickable {
        id: id_flickable
        anchors.fill: parent

        GridView {
            id: id_gridView
            anchors.fill: parent

            model: DelegateModel {
                id: id_delegateModel

                // sample code here, the model is actually stored in C++ 
                model: [ { buttonName:"A" } , { buttonName: "B" } , { buttonName:"C" } ]

                delegate: RowLayout {
                    id: id_delegate 

                    property int modelIndex
                    required property int index
                    //required property string buttonName   // -> does not compile
                    //required property var buttonName      // -> does not compile

                    Label {
                        id: id_numeration
                        text: String(id_delegate.DelegateModel.itemsIndex + 1)
                    }

                    DropArea {
                        id: id_dropArea
                        property int visualIndex: id_delegate.DelegateModel.itemsIndex

                        onEntered: function (drag) {
                            let from = (drag.source as DragArea).visualIndex
                            let to = id_dragArea.visualIndex
                            id_delegateModel.items.move(from, to)
                        }

                        onDropped: function (drag) {
                            let from = id_delegate.modelIndex
                            let to = (drag.source as DragArea).visualIndex
                            // save in c++ model possible here but not wanted
                            //ctx.move(from, to)
                        }

                        DragArea {
                            id: id_dragArea
                            dragParent: id_gridView
                            visualIndex: id_dropArea.visualIndex

                            Component.onCompleted:
                                modelIndex = visualIndex
                            }
                            onPressed: {
                                id_delegate.modelIndex = visualIndex
                            }
                            onReleased: {
                            }

                            Button {
                                id:  id_gridTextBtn

                                property int visualIndex: id_dropArea.visualIndex

                                //text: buttonName  // <- does not compile
                                text: id_delegateModel.model[id_delegate.index].buttonName
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The code is a mix from the official sample Qt Quick Examples - Drag and Drop | Qt Quick 5.15.17 and another sample QML Drag and Drop including reordering the C++ model - Raymii.org.
Does anyone know how to read and write the visualIndex from outside the delegate? The reason I don't want to set the order to the C++ directly is that there should be a Cancel button which needs to revert all changes made since opening the window. Maybe you have a better idea how to do it?
Similar question:
can I save and retrieve the delegate of a delegatemodel in qml

Start by reading about the Qt's undo framework and decide what you want to do from there between it and what you described in your question.

Thanks. I was also thinking about storing a list of changes and rollback when the user clicks the cancel button.
